# Poner un botón de confirmación antes de realizar la acción

Tags: ajax

Dispongo de un código en el que realizo un borrado de un campo, pero quiero poner una pantalla de alerta solicitando la confirmación.

Estoy intentando varias maneras pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

> // Codigo para elminar un perfil de usuario
>       $('.eliminarLibro').on('click', function (e) {
>           e.preventDefault();

```
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var tipo = $(this).attr('data-type');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'accion': 'eliminarLibro'
        },
        url: 'acciones' + tipo + '.php',
        success: function (data) {
            var resultado = JSON.parse(data);
            if (resultado.respuesta == 'libroEliminado') {
                swal({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Buen trabajo',
                    text: 'El libro se elimino correctamente',
                    allowEscapeKey: true,
                    allowOutsideClick: true,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo solicitar la confirmación antes de enviar el **ajax**, y puedes hacerlo de varias formas. Una de ellas es mostrar un `confirm` con 2 botones, *Cancelar* y *Aceptar*:

```
$(".eliminarLibro").click(function() {
  var confirmacion = confirm("¿Seguro que quieres borrar el libro?");
  if (confirmacion  == true) {
    // Se ha pulsado aceptar
  } else {
    // Se ha pulsado cancelar
  }
});
```

Ahora, deberías cambiar `Se ha pulsado aceptar` por `e.preventDefault();` si eso es lo que quieres hacer.

Si quieres hacer algo cuando se pulsa cancelar, deberías cambiarlo por `Se ha pulsado cancelar`, de lo contrario simplemente borrarlo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.